# Enity is not mapped - hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to create a small project with hibernate, but i got that error "Type is not mapped [select o from Type o]", I added mapping in hibernate.cfg.xml but still error.

Type.java:

```
package com.formation.gestionprojet.doa.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="Type")
public class Type implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private Long id;

private String name;

private String description;

private String active;




public Type() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(String active) {
    this.active = active;
}   

}
```

hibernate.org.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>


<session-factory>

<!--  database connection setting -->

<property name ="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestion_projet?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</property>
<property name="connection.username">root</property>
<property name= "connection.password">root</property>

<!-- Dialect -->
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

<!-- Disable the second level cache -->

<property name="cache.provider_class" >org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

<!-- echo all executed SQL to stdout -->

<property name="show_sql">true</property>

<!-- Drope and re-create the database -->
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

<!-- mapping -->


<mapping class= "com.formation.gestionprojet.doa.entity.Type"/>


</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

hibernateUtil.java:

```
package com.formation.gestionprojet.utils;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class HibernateUtil
{
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    static
    {
        try
        {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("config/hibernate.cfg.xml");

            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }
        catch (HibernateException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Error creating Session: " + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    } 



    public static Session openSession()
    {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    } 


    public static Session getCurrentSession()
    {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    } 


    public static void close(){
        if(sessionFactory!=null){
            sessionFactory.close();
        }

    }


}
```

Test.Java

```
package com.formation.gestionprojet.utils;

import org.hibernate.Session;



public class Test {

    static Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        session.createQuery("select o from Type o").list();



    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enity is not mapped \[select o from Type o\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124615/enity-is-not-mapped-select-o-from-type-o)

Answer (score 0):

First things first, Type is part of the JPA/Hibernate API. So consider renaming it, e.g. MyType or something similar.

Secondly, select is not mandatory in HQL. So you can simply et everything with only FROM clause.

Thirdly, try using fully qualified name of the class in the query.

```
"FROM com.formation.gestionprojet.doa.entity.MyType"
```